# Strong solution of inviscid Burgers' equation with initial data $u(x,0)=x^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm studying for an exam and having trouble solving the following:

> Find the strong solution to the inviscid Burgers' equation
>    $u_t+uu_x=0$ with initial data $u(x,0)=x^2$

Using the initial data, I've found $u(x,t)=f(x-ut)=(x-ut)^2=x^2-2xut+u^2t^2$

but I'm not sure how to proceed from there. Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was asked before ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/687651/147263) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/867759/147263)) but never got an explanation beyond formal manipulations, so here goes. To find a sensible solution of the Burgers' equation (to the extent that it's at all possible with your initial data) one has to consider the characteristics. From each point $(x_0,0)$ begins a characteristic of the form $x=x_0+tx_0^2$. Solving this for $x_0$, we find
$$x_0=\frac{1}{2t}(-1\pm \sqrt{1+4xt}) \tag{1}$$
Therefore:

1. Through every point $(x,t)$ with $xt>-1/4$ there pass two characteristics.
2. There are no characteristics passing through $(x,t)$ with $xt<-1/t$.

Here is an illustration so far.

[image: selfint]

In order to sort this out, we have to terminate some characteristics sooner, so that such intersections do not occur. In the equation (1), the $+$ sign is preferable when $t\to0$, as it gets us $x_0\to x$ and subsequently $u(x,t)\to x^2$. The $-$ sign corresponds to characteristics coming from way out in the left. They all are tangent to the hyperbola $xt=-1/4$ and should terminate there. Here is a cleaned up picture:

[image: correct]

And the corresponding solution:

$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{(2t)^2}(-1+ \sqrt{1+4xt})^2,\quad x>-\frac1{4t} $$

Comment: this was really helpful, thanks!