# Limit of the derivative of the solution to Burgers Equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

Let $u$ be the solution to Burgers equation 
$$u_t + u u_x = \epsilon u_{xx}$$
I want to prove that $$\lim_ {x \to \pm \infty}\partial_x u(x,t) \, \, \,\text{exists}.$$
But I don't even know if it's true

Answer (score 0):

It isn't true in general. Consider for instance $\epsilon=0$ and the initial-value problem $u(x,0) = x^2$. Then the solution $u(x,t)$ at $t>0$ isn't defined over the whole real line (cf. various [related posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1203654) on this site), so that there is little chance to be able to compute $u_x$ as $x$ approaches $-\infty$.